# Can you SNMP poll the ARP table on Cisco ACE?

Tags: networking, cisco, snmp, arp, cisco-ace

I'm trying to get a MAC <=> IP mapping from a Cisco ACE. Unfortunately according to [this table](http://www.cisco.com/en/US/docs/interfaces_modules/services_modules/ace/vA5_1_0/configuration/administration/guide/snmp.html#wp1181302), while it supports IP-MIB the `ipNetToMediaTable` and `ipNetToPhysicalTable` subtrees are not supported. Is there any other way to get this information, maybe with the CISCO-SLB... MIBS (in which I poked around but failed to find anything)?

As our management application has no CLI access, I have to use an SNMP based solution.

Answer (score 0):

This is not possible via SNMP as long as those subtrees are not supported. Regardless of the MIB you use, the values won't be populated from the ACE.